# jquery doesnt seem to load when i call the page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, validation

Hi Im having trouble loading jquery for my website, it is composed of 1 main GUI and many other pages that is loded using the ajax the main problem is that the main GUI doesnt seem to load the mini pages that has jquery or validations in them can anybody help me with this one?

Here is the Script for the main page

```
<script src="gapi2.js"></script>//This is the jquery 
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function(){//This is the start of the jquery     
       $("#contact_us").click(function(){
           $("#contact").load("plist.php?id");
       });
    });

</script>
```

This is the html

```
<a id="contact_us">Contact Us</a>
<div id='contact'></div>
 //This is for the validation
<script src="jquery-validation2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-validation.js"></script>
<script> $.validate(); </script>
```

This is the second page

```
<form action='page2.php' method='POST'>
Name:  <input type='text'>
Age: <input type='text'>
</form>
```

i have tried many jquery but it doesnt seem to be able to help me validate it it just goes straigth to the next page and saves it and it doesnt even validate the page any help would really be appreciated and thanks!

Comment: would you plz tell us how you are validating, plz post the validation code too.

Comment: When do you initially load the jquery library?

Comment: hi i edited and add the validation or the script that calls the validation

Comment: did u get any js error in firebug console

Comment: no it runs fine when i load it using the url but when i use the index and load it using the ajax the validation doesnt seem to happen

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function(){//This is NOT the start of the jquery     
       $("#contact_us").click(function(){
           $("#contact").load("plist.php?id");
       });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: hi what does this code do? because it seems that it looks like the original one and i have added the code

Comment: Loads jQuery liibrary

Comment: the library is already loaded this is the code for it                                                                   <script src="gapi2.js"></script>

Comment: That looks like the name of Google API and not JQuery.

Comment: no i downloaded it because i always work offline so i can use it even of i dont have any network

Comment: Whether you call it externally from a CDN, your server directory, or your localhost; The same principles apply. Good Luck